# How to swap between big/little endian for unsigned 8, 16, and 32-bit integers?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I have collected these from various places, but they are incomplete and not sure what the optimal approach is, any help would be appreciated. Looking for a generic cross-platform way to do this for u8, u16, and u32, so I can translate this to a few different programming languages (custom and regular PLs).

```
function swap16(val) {
  return ((val & 0xFF) << 8)
        | ((val >> 8) & 0xFF);
}

function swap32(val) {
  return ((val & 0xFF) << 24)
        | ((val & 0xFF00) << 8)
        | ((val >> 8) & 0xFF00)
        | ((val >> 24) & 0xFF);
}

function unsignedSwap16(num) {
  return (num>>8) | (num<<8);
}

function unsignedSwap32(num) {
  return ((num>>24)&0xff) | // move byte 3 to byte 0
  ((num<<8)&0xff0000) | // move byte 1 to byte 2
  ((num>>8)&0xff00) | // move byte 2 to byte 1
  ((num<<24)&0xff000000); // byte 0 to byte 3
}
```

Comment: What is incomplete about them?

Comment: Unless you're doing this for learning, you should strongly consider using a library, e.g. Boost. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/endian/doc/index.html

Comment: Both learning and for a custom programming language.

Comment: `unsignedSwap16` needs to be ANDed, otherwise the results could be larger than 16 bits.

Answer (score 0):

no bit-masking or bit-shifting is needed. I usually do this in C++ using `union`:

```cpp
U32 v32; // your values to swap
U16 v16;
U8  v08;

union converter // helper union
   {
   U32 u32[1];
   U16 u16[2];
   U8  u08[4];
   } a;
U8 b; // helper temp BYTE for swap

// swap32
a.u32[0]=v32;
b=a.u8[0]; a.u8[0]=a.u8[3]; a.u8[3]=b;
b=a.u8[1]; a.u8[1]=a.u8[2]; a.u8[2]=b;
v32=a.u32[0];

// swap16
a.u16[0]=v16;
b=a.u8[0]; a.u8[0]=a.u8[1]; a.u8[1]=b;
v16=a.u16[0];
```

or the same with `pointers`:

```cpp
U32 v32; // your values to swap
U16 v16;
U8  v08;
U8  *p,b; // helper BYTE pointer and temp for swap

// swap32
p=(U8*)(&v32);
b=p[0]; p[0]=p[3]; p[3]=b;
b=p[1]; p[1]=p[2]; p[2]=b;

// swap16
p=(U8*)(&v16);
b=p[0]; p[0]=p[1]; p[1]=b;
```

Comment: Is the second solution safe about pointer aliasing? The first solution seems to be fine.

Comment: @Sebastian depends on compiler, some weird "compilers" like GC are picky and need additional stuff like `dynamic_cast` or `static_cast` or use temp pointer variable ... but that is just the syntax of the pointer assignment ... functionality should be fine as we are just swapping BYTE data and not accessing it in specific order ...

Comment: Okay, converting to `std::byte`, `char` and `unsigned char` pointers is allowed; signed char would not be.

Comment: @Sebastian `char` is signed already ... and sign is irrelevant this is pure copy no conversion is involved ...

Comment: Already signed is only true for: int = signed int, not generally true for char = signed char (it is a different type and may also be unsigned); in addition, for pointer to signed char writes the compiler may assume that it does not influence variables/memory of other type, e.g. any uint32 or uint16 and can optimize it out. All this is about C++, which you stated in the answer as language.

Comment: For example gcc uses the type aliasing optimization potential with -O2, -O3 or -Os (if you do not also specify -fno-strict-aliasing). See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast (section Type Aliasing, which does not state `signed char` as allowed) and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types (section Character Types)